# Multi-colored border EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I'm trying to figure out how to make a custom EditText that has black borders along it's right and left sides, a green border on top, and a blue border on the bottom.  See below:
[image]

I'm fairly new to Android development and I've spent quite a lot of time reading their documentation but haven't had any luck finding anything on this kind of customization.  I know in CSS you can just use the border-right, border-left, etc... properties but not sure if it's that straightforward in Android development.  I'm looking for the solution that is the most compatible, preferably from version 2.3 (Gingerbread).

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to make a custom image to use as the background.  It's relatively straight forward, you'll want to use a 9-patch as described [in the 2D graphics guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch).

Once you have that, you'll put it in your res/drawable folder of your project, and then use it with the EditText in XML as

```
<EditText
    android:background="@drawable/my_custom_background"
    ...
/>
```

Comment: I tend to stay away from image solutions like this because I'm afraid of the quality of the image being distorted depending on how big or how small it needs to be stretched, as well as handling for retina.

Comment: A 9patch has its stretchable zones specifically marked by you, so provided you do it correctly, there won't be any distortion.  For a simple border like you want, there won't be any distortion at all, even if you plastered it on a display 100 feet wide 360,000 pixels long.

Answer (score 0):

create a [`LayerList`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) with a square colored in the wanted gradient, and above it a white square with some borders. then use this drawable as your `TextView` background.

Comment: Could you give me a code sample?  Your explanation sounds very confusing to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Multi-colored border EditText using 9-patch or in xml `<layer-list>`
here i am creating Multi-colored border EditText programmatically.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 private TextView mTextView;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      customTextViewWithBorder();

}

private void customTextViewWithBorder(){
mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
         // Initialize some new ColorDrawable objects
                        ColorDrawable leftBorder = new ColorDrawable(Color.RED);
                        ColorDrawable topBorder = new ColorDrawable(Color.GREEN);
                        ColorDrawable rightBorder = new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE);
                        ColorDrawable bottomBorder = new ColorDrawable(Color.YELLOW);
                        ColorDrawable background = new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE);

                        // Initialize an array of Drawable objects
                        Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[]{
                                leftBorder, // Red color
                                topBorder, // Green color
                                rightBorder, // Blue color
                                bottomBorder, // Yellow color
                                background // White background
                        };
     // Initialize a new LayerDrawable
    LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
    // Red layer padding, draw left border
                    layerDrawable.setLayerInset(0,0,0,15,0);

                    // Green layer padding, draw top border
                    layerDrawable.setLayerInset(1,15,0,0,15);

                    // Blue layer padding, draw right border
                    layerDrawable.setLayerInset(2,15,15,0,0);

                    // Yellow layer padding, draw bottom border
                    layerDrawable.setLayerInset(3,15,15,15,0);

                    // White layer, draw the background
                    layerDrawable.setLayerInset(4,15,15,15,15);
     mTextView.setBackground(layerDrawable);

                    // Set the TextView padding
                    mTextView.setPadding(25,25,25,25);

}
```

Source [android--code](http://android--code.blogspot.in/2015/11/android-how-to-create-layerdrawable.html)